# Is there a 'standard' way to get to the values in $$route?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am currently using `$route.current.$$route` to get at some "non-standard" parameters I am attaching to route objects via the `$routeProvider`. Non-standard because they're not the three properties mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) under `current.locals`.

Hence, my `locals` is empty and I am having to use `$$route` to get at them. But I fear this is a hack and my code will break with a future update. Is there a better way to get at these values?

Comment: So you need to inject additional stuff into the controller associated with a given route? Use resolve as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Comment: I'm not associating controllers directly via the router, I am using `ng-controller` inside the view... so I cannot use that :( Thanks for pointing it out though, I really like the promise resolution part of it.